# C# WPF Add button to expander header

Tags: c#, wpf

i have some code that programmatically adds expanders:

```
foreach (Purchase p in purchases)
{
    databaseView.panelPurchase.Children.Add(new Expander
    {
        Name = "exp" + p.ID,
        Header = p.Model + " " + p.ReceiptDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),
        Content = new PurchaseView { DataContext = p }
    });
}
```

Does someone know how to add button to the right corner of the expander header programmatically?

Comment: The question is, do you really need to do this programically? There are easier solution. You could use some DataBinding and styling in xaml, and keep all the data with easy access to it. If not, you could create grid that is made like this, but in C# instead of Xaml:

Comment: <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Some text"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button on the right" Margin="0,0,40,0"/>
            </Grid>